# Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, syntax-error

Here's my code (TaskManager.swift):

```
import UIKit

var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager ()

struct task {
    var name = "untitled"
    var desc = "none"
}

class TaskManager: NSObject {
    var tasks = task[]()

    func addTask (name: String, desc: String) {
        tasks.append (task (name: name, desc: desc))
    }
}
```

then I got this

> /Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/RandomTries/ToDoList/ToDoList/TaskManager.swift:11:21: Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type

It says

> Fix-it: Insert "["

I clicked it, then that line (line 11) turned to this:

```
var tasks = [task[]()
```

and I got these errors

> /Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/RandomTries/ToDoList/ToDoList/TaskManager.swift:11:26: Expected ']' in container literal expression
>   /Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/RandomTries/ToDoList/ToDoList/TaskManager.swift:11:26: Expected ',' separator
>   /Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/RandomTries/ToDoList/ToDoList/TaskManager.swift:13:5: Expected expression in container literal
>   /Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/RandomTries/ToDoList/ToDoList/TaskManager.swift:14:15: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(task)'

Thanks for any advices!

and here is another 2 errors in FirstViewController.swift:

> /Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/RandomTries/ToDoList/ToDoList/FirstViewController.swift:21:14: 'text' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift
>   /Users/David/Documents/360Drive/Xcode/Try/RandomTries/ToDoList/ToDoList/FirstViewController.swift:22:30: Cannot assign to 'detailTextLabel' in 'cell'

and here's the code

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskMgr.tasks.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell (style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default")
        cell.textLabel = ""
        cell.detailTextLabel = ""
        //cell.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
        //cell.detailTextLabel = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like *Fix-it* blew it.  Swift uses brackets around the type.  The correct version is this:

```
var tasks = [task]()
```

This is the *shorthand* notation; there is a longer version:

```
var tasks = Array<task>()
```

but the shorthand version is preferred.

Comment: cell.textLabel is a UILabel, not text. You're trying to assign a string to a label. You need to do cell.textLabel.text

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not proper.
Task array can be initialised like this:-

```
Var tasks = [Task]()
```

Then u can use append method add "Task" object in it.

```
tasks.append(your Task object)
```